# Android instanceof detecting all widgets?

Tags: java, android, view, instanceof

I'm trying to set a font across all `TextView`'s by iterating through the `LinearLayout`'s views and using `instanceof`.

The form currently consists of 4 `TextView`'s and one `Button`.

The below code is detecting all `View`s, even the `Button` as a `TextView`?

```
    /* Set fonts */
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_screenincourse_wrapper);
    for (int i = 0; i < ll.getChildCount(); i++) {          
        View v = ll.getChildAt(i);          
        if (v instanceof TextView) {
            ((TextView) v).setTypeface(Fonts.get3dDumbFont(this));
        }
    }
```

If I log each view's class name it returns the TextView and the Button so I know the correct controls are being picked up.

The problem is the Button and TextView's fonts are being set, and I only want the `TextView`'s.

I have found a work around and that is to do the following but am intrigued as to why the above code does not work as expected.

```
    /* Set fonts */
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_screenincourse_wrapper);
    for (int i = 0; i < ll.getChildCount(); i++) {          
        View v = ll.getChildAt(i);          
        if (v.getClass().getName().contains("TextView")) {
            ((TextView) v).setTypeface(Fonts.get3dDumbFont(this));
        }
    }
```

Is it because both Button and TextView are of type `View`? If so, what would be the correct way about doing this?

Any help appreciated, thanks. Ricky.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, Button is a subclass of TextView! That's why you see it as a TextView (it is also a TextView).

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

```
public class Button extends TextView
```

You could make a second if `instanceof` to exclude Buttons or use

```
if (v.getClass() == TextView.class)
```

But this won't match any other subclasses of TextView (if you use them).

Answer (score 2):

It is simple

[Button Class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) extends [TextView Class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)

Check the [documentaion](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html)